# subset data.table columns by matching with a list

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I have the following `data.table`:

```
dt1 <- data.table(apple = c(1:5),
                  bananas = c(5:1),
                  carrots = c(6:10),
                  donuts = c(11:15))
```

and the following `list`:

```
names_to_keep <- c("apple", "carrots")
```

I need to create a new `data.table` from `dt1` that only includes columns who's names are included in `names_to_keep`.

Desired result:

```
#   apple carrots
#1:     1       6
#2:     2       7
#3:     3       8
#4:     4       9
#5:     5      10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `with=FALSE`, also see `vignette("datatable-faq")`:

```
dt1[, names_to_keep, with=FALSE]

#   apple carrots
#1:     1       6
#2:     2       7
#3:     3       8
#4:     4       9
#5:     5      10
```

Or as @Frank commented, there's a new syntax for this now:

```
dt1[,..names_to_keep]

#   apple carrots
#1:     1       6
#2:     2       7
#3:     3       8
#4:     4       9
#5:     5      10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dt1 <- data.table(as.data.frame(dt1)[,names_to_keep])
dt1
     apple carrots
1:     1       6
2:     2       7
3:     3       8
4:     4       9
5:     5      10
```